# Join max records in Postresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables:

```
products
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Orange |
| 2  | Juice  |
| 3  | Fance  |
+----+--------+
reviews
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | created_at | price | product_id |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| 1  | 12/12/20   | 2     | 1          |
| 2  | 12/14/20   | 4     | 1          |
| 3  | 12/15/20   | 5     | 2          |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

How can I get list of products ordered by price of most recent (max created_at) review?

```
+------------+--------+-----------+-------+
| product_id | name   | review_id | price |
+------------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 2          | Juice  | 3         | 5     |
| 1          | Orance | 2         | 4     |
| 3          | Fance  |           |       |
+------------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

I use latest PostgreSQL.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please show your query. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't understood: Do you order by product, price oder date (which date format is this? mm/dd/yy?)

Comment: @S-Man: A date in a database has no fomat (unless it is unappropriately strored as a string or integer).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I know but I don't understand the format of his/her string representation ;)

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, it's obviously American: mm/dd/yy. And the order of the result is by price descending ("list of products ordered by price").

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ORDER BY price DESC would result in 4 3 2 but it's 4 3 null. Does he mean the highest price per product? But what is the part with the most recent?

Comment: Maybe first: Most recent per product and then order by price DESC

Comment: Not only maybe: "of most recent (max created_at) Review".

Comment: most recent price for each product. and result table needs to be sorted by price.

Comment: @Molfar: There are several ways to write such query. How far have you got with yours? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't know where to start.

Comment: format of created_at is default rails, "2019-01-25 15:42:54.913415" - in my example I just simplified it.

Comment: Okay. You want all rows of `products`. You certainly know how to do that. You should also know about outer joins. You want the latest review per product. That's the one with the max date or the one where exists no newer review. You can use subqueries, `DISTINCT ON`, `ROW_NUMBER()`. You should be able to come up with *something*.

Comment: as I mentioned to @S-Man distinct on does not work because it neeeds to be sorted by id first, and it breaks order by price.

Comment: @Molfar But you can do a second order after the DISTINCT as I did in my corrected version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f9fe8ec97a02b8ab06423ca52ae3740b)

Using `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id)
        p.id,
        p.name,
        r.id as review_id,
        r.price
    FROM
        reviews r
    RIGHT JOIN products p ON r.product_id = p.id
    ORDER BY p.id, r.created_at DESC NULLS LAST
) s
ORDER BY price DESC NULLS LAST
```

1. Join both tables (`products LEFT JOIN review` or `review RIGHT JOIN products`).
2. Now you have to do your orders. First you want to group the products together. Then you want to get the most recent entry per product (date in descending order to get the most recent as first row).
3. `DISTINCT ON` filters always the first row of an ordered group. So you get the most recent entry per product.
4. To sort your product rows put 1-3 into a subquery and order by `price` afterwards.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2eee6ef0595239d64a01b46b9e42171e It doesn work because it sorts products by id first, and breaks sorting by price. I my fiddle product with id 2 (price 5) should be at the first position.

Comment: yeah just saw it too. fixed it

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT ON` and an outer join is a good approach, but I would handle this as:

```
SELECT . . .  -- whatever columns you want
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.product_id) r.*
      FROM reviews r
      ORDER BY r.product_id, r.created_at DESC NULLS LAST
     ) r
     ON r.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.price DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The difference in doing `DISTINCT ON` before the `JOIN` or after may look minor.  But this version of the query can take advantage of an index on `reviews(product_id, created_at desc)`.  And that could be a big performance win on a lot of data.

Indexes cannot be used for an `ORDER BY` that mixes columns from different tables.